# Updating columns based on if a entry for a record exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 1 table which records server state information every night.  I reference that table with a list of every server in the enterprise saved in another table, and a query runs against that to check to see if an entry for that servername was included in the Maint table within the last few hours.  That part works well.

```
Lookup table:
---------------
serverID 
serverName 
isActive

Maintenance Table:
 --------------
ServerID 
ServerName 
LastAttemptedDateTimeStamp

--This part is working fine.
```

Here is what functionality I would like to add.  I want to update the table daily (overwriting all the old info) and have a record for every entry in the lookup table.  If a entry for the server in the look up table exists in the Maint table within the last 24 hours, then put a SUCCESS bit (1) in the row, updating LastAttemptedDateTime and LastSuccDateTimeUpdate.

If a entry for that table does not exist, then put a FAILED bit (0) and do NOT update the LastSuccDateTimeUpdate

```
Reporting Table:
----------------
-LastAttemptedDateTime
-LastSuccDateTimeUpdate
-WasSuccessfull (bit) 0 or 1
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm looking up CASE as an alertnative of IF/THEN for SQL Server to figure out the 'WasSuccessfull' part.  IF or CASE datetime is over 24 hours old, then put a 0 for successfull.  If datetime is under 24 hours old, put a 1 for success.  Not quite sure how to do the logic.

Comment: Can't be solved with the current information. We are missing columns (at least 1 datestamp in lookup table) and having 2 reporting tables it seems. Describe the 2 tables, populate with some test data in order for us, to have a chance of solving it. Also describe the desired output for the test data

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pseudo-code using case:

```
Update ReportingTable R
SET Col1 = SomeValue,
    Col2 = SomeOtherValue,
    WasSuccesful = CASE
                   WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LookupTable WHERE ...) THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                   END
```

If you finish your table structure listed in your OP I can be more specific.  I'm assuming there is a way to link a `Reporting` record to a `Lookup` or `Maintenance` record...

Comment: Thanks JNK, that is the relevent table structure, the only thing I would add would be to include ServerID in the reporting table, the rest I can figure out.  

So essentially, we would have only 1 entry in the reporting table per item in the lookup table, so I figured a 'update table' statement would be best.  If a record does not exist in the Maintenance table in the time specified (24 hours let's say, I have this code written already), then I need to put a '0' for successful, and maintain the 'last updated' date.  If a record does exist, put a 1 and update the last updated column.  HALP! ty